# Как создать блок как на картинке с помощью bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

Как реализовать такую сетку для фотографий на bootstrap?
[image: Как нужно]
[image: Как получилось]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В 4 бутстрапе максимально близкий результат, без использования дополнительных скриптов, вы можете получить с помощью [карточек](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdncore.adonismale.com/monthly_2017_01/58684fd638626_DBHelpTutorialsGalleryfa-image.png.3deb9fbfc256c15f425354c36782a1b1.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0 card-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdncore.adonismale.com/monthly_2017_01/58684fd638626_DBHelpTutorialsGalleryfa-image.png.3deb9fbfc256c15f425354c36782a1b1.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://cdncore.adonismale.com/monthly_2017_01/58684fd638626_DBHelpTutorialsGalleryfa-image.png.3deb9fbfc256c15f425354c36782a1b1.png" alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3 text-right">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте лучше библиотеку для JavaScript, например [Masonry
Cascading grid layout library](https://masonry.desandro.com/)